# FullCalendar, get current date in selectOverlap callback?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar 5 and the `interactionPlugin` in React.  I'm wanting to allow users to select any date without an event AND any date that an event ends on.  So if there is an event that goes from April 1st to the 3rd, I want to be able to select the 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. but not the 2nd.  Does that make sense?

I'm using the `selectOverlap` and it fires when the user drags the mouse over an event. I'm able to get the events start and end dates but not the date range the user has selected.  Is there a way to get the date range the user has selected in the `selectOverlap` callback?  If not, is there another callback I can use to get which date the mouse is currently over?

```
<FullCalendar
    ref={calendarRef}
    timeZone={timezone}
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, momentTimezonePlugin]}
    selectOverlap={handleSelectOverlap}
    ...
/>

const handleSelectOverlap = (event) => {
    console.log("end", event.end);
    // I have the event's end date but how do I get the current date the mouse is over?
    return false;
};
```

Comment: You might have to use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents and then check the selection against each of the events yourself.

Comment: P.s. "current date" implies today's date, or the date the calendar is currently set to. I worked out what you meant after reading it a few times, but "date range the user has selected" would be a much more accurate way of describing what you're talking about.

Comment: @ADyson Post your first comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer, that was exactly what I needed.  (I also edited the question text as suggested)

Comment: Your wish is my command...see below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do this via selectOverlap - it only really allows for a simple yes/no as to whether it overlaps or not, it can't tell you *where* it overlaps.

I think you would have to make your own validation by using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow - which gives you the start and end date of the range the user has just selected - and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents - to get all the events currently on the calendar - and then check the selection against each of the events yourself.